# getting lnk2019 error when compile a program using qt creator and eigen library

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, eigen

I try to compile a project in qt and after i link the necessary libs i ghet the fallowing linking error :

```
labelbox.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall LabelImage::setAxis(class Eigen::Matrix<double,4,4,0,4,4>)" (?setAxis@LabelImage@@QAEXV?$Matrix@N$03$03$0A@$03$03@Eigen@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ImageView::setRotMat(class Eigen::Matrix<double,4,4,0,4,4> &)" (?setRotMat@ImageView@@QAEXAAV?$Matrix@N$03$03$0A@$03$03@Eigen@@@Z)
```

If i go in the matrix.h from eigen i see the next problems :
In the fallowing lines of code :

```
 template<typename _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options, int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols>
class Matrix
  : public PlainObjectBase<Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> >
{
  public:

    /** \brief Base class typedef.
      * \sa PlainObjectBase
      */
    typedef PlainObjectBase<Matrix> Base;

    enum { Options = _Options };

    EIGEN_DENSE_PUBLIC_INTERFACE(Matrix)

    typedef typename Base::PlainObject PlainObject;

    using Base::base;
    using Base::coeffRef;

    /**
      * \brief Assigns matrices to each other.
      *
      * \note This is a special case of the templated operator=. Its purpose is
      * to prevent a default operator= from hiding the templated operator=.
      *
      * \callgraph
      */
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& other)
    {
      return Base::_set(other);
    }

    /** \internal
      * \brief Copies the value of the expression \a other into \c *this with automatic resizing.
      *
      * *this might be resized to match the dimensions of \a other. If *this was a null matrix (not already initialized),
      * it will be initialized.
      *
      * Note that copying a row-vector into a vector (and conversely) is allowed.
      * The resizing, if any, is then done in the appropriate way so that row-vectors
      * remain row-vectors and vectors remain vectors.
      */
    template<typename OtherDerived>
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix& operator=(const DenseBase<OtherDerived>& other)
    {
      return Base::_set(other);
    }

    /* Here, doxygen failed to copy the brief information when using \copydoc */

    /**
      * \brief Copies the generic expression \a other into *this.
      * \copydetails DenseBase::operator=(const EigenBase<OtherDerived> &other)
      */
    template<typename OtherDerived>
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix& operator=(const EigenBase<OtherDerived> &other)
    {
      return Base::operator=(other);
    }

    template<typename OtherDerived>
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix& operator=(const ReturnByValue<OtherDerived>& func)
    {
      return Base::operator=(func);
    }

    /** \brief Default constructor.
      *
      * For fixed-size matrices, does nothing.
      *
      * For dynamic-size matrices, creates an empty matrix of size 0. Does not allocate any array. Such a matrix
      * is called a null matrix. This constructor is the unique way to create null matrices: resizing
      * a matrix to 0 is not supported.
      *
      * \sa resize(Index,Index)
      */
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix() : Base()
    {
      Base::_check_template_params();
      EIGEN_INITIALIZE_COEFFS_IF_THAT_OPTION_IS_ENABLED
    }

    // FIXME is it still needed
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    explicit Matrix(internal::constructor_without_unaligned_array_assert)
      : Base(internal::constructor_without_unaligned_array_assert())
    { Base::_check_template_params(); EIGEN_INITIALIZE_COEFFS_IF_THAT_OPTION_IS_ENABLED }

#if EIGEN_HAS_RVALUE_REFERENCES
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    Matrix(Matrix&& other) EIGEN_NOEXCEPT_IF(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<Scalar>::value)
      : Base(std::move(other))
    {
      Base::_check_template_params();
      if (RowsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic && ColsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic)
        Base::_set_noalias(other);
    }
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& other) EIGEN_NOEXCEPT_IF(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<Scalar>::value)
    {
      other.swap(*this);
      return *this;
    }
#endif

    #ifndef EIGEN_PARSED_BY_DOXYGEN

    // This constructor is for both 1x1 matrices and dynamic vectors
    template<typename T>
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE explicit Matrix(const T& x)
    {
      Base::_check_template_params();
      Base::template _init1<T>(x);
    }

    template<typename T0, typename T1>
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix(const T0& x, const T1& y)
    {
      Base::_check_template_params();
      Base::template _init2<T0,T1>(x, y);
    }
    #else
    /** \brief Constructs a fixed-sized matrix initialized with coefficients starting at \a data */
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    explicit Matrix(const Scalar *data);

    /** \brief Constructs a vector or row-vector with given dimension. \only_for_vectors
      *
      * This is useful for dynamic-size vectors. For fixed-size vectors,
      * it is redundant to pass these parameters, so one should use the default constructor
      * Matrix() instead.
      * 
      * \warning This constructor is disabled for fixed-size \c 1x1 matrices. For instance,
      * calling Matrix<double,1,1>(1) will call the initialization constructor: Matrix(const Scalar&).
      * For fixed-size \c 1x1 matrices it is therefore recommended to use the default
      * constructor Matrix() instead, especially when using one of the non standard
      * \c EIGEN_INITIALIZE_MATRICES_BY_{ZERO,\c NAN} macros (see \ref TopicPreprocessorDirectives).
      */
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE explicit Matrix(Index dim);
    /** \brief Constructs an initialized 1x1 matrix with the given coefficient */
    Matrix(const Scalar& x);
    /** \brief Constructs an uninitialized matrix with \a rows rows and \a cols columns.
      *
      * This is useful for dynamic-size matrices. For fixed-size matrices,
      * it is redundant to pass these parameters, so one should use the default constructor
      * Matrix() instead.
      * 
      * \warning This constructor is disabled for fixed-size \c 1x2 and \c 2x1 vectors. For instance,
      * calling Matrix2f(2,1) will call the initialization constructor: Matrix(const Scalar& x, const Scalar& y).
      * For fixed-size \c 1x2 or \c 2x1 vectors it is therefore recommended to use the default
      * constructor Matrix() instead, especially when using one of the non standard
      * \c EIGEN_INITIALIZE_MATRICES_BY_{ZERO,\c NAN} macros (see \ref TopicPreprocessorDirectives).
      */
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    Matrix(Index rows, Index cols);

    /** \brief Constructs an initialized 2D vector with given coefficients */
    Matrix(const Scalar& x, const Scalar& y);
    #endif

    /** \brief Constructs an initialized 3D vector with given coefficients */
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix(const Scalar& x, const Scalar& y, const Scalar& z)
    {
      Base::_check_template_params();
      EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_VECTOR_SPECIFIC_SIZE(Matrix, 3)
      m_storage.data()[0] = x;
      m_storage.data()[1] = y;
      m_storage.data()[2] = z;
    }
    /** \brief Constructs an initialized 4D vector with given coefficients */
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix(const Scalar& x, const Scalar& y, const Scalar& z, const Scalar& w)
    {
      Base::_check_template_params();
      EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT_VECTOR_SPECIFIC_SIZE(Matrix, 4)
      m_storage.data()[0] = x;
      m_storage.data()[1] = y;
      m_storage.data()[2] = z;
      m_storage.data()[3] = w;
    }


    /** \brief Copy constructor */
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix(const Matrix& other) : Base(other)
    { }

    /** \brief Copy constructor for generic expressions.
      * \sa MatrixBase::operator=(const EigenBase<OtherDerived>&)
      */
    template<typename OtherDerived>
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Matrix(const EigenBase<OtherDerived> &other)
      : Base(other.derived())
    { }

    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC inline Index innerStride() const { return 1; }
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC inline Index outerStride() const { return this->innerSize(); }

    /////////// Geometry module ///////////

    template<typename OtherDerived>
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    explicit Matrix(const RotationBase<OtherDerived,ColsAtCompileTime>& r);
    template<typename OtherDerived>
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    Matrix& operator=(const RotationBase<OtherDerived,ColsAtCompileTime>& r);

    // allow to extend Matrix outside Eigen
    #ifdef EIGEN_MATRIX_PLUGIN
    #include EIGEN_MATRIX_PLUGIN
    #endif

  protected:
    template <typename Derived, typename OtherDerived, bool IsVector>
    friend struct internal::conservative_resize_like_impl;

    using Base::m_storage;
};

/** \defgroup matrixtypedefs Global matrix typedefs
  *
  * \ingroup Core_Module
  *
  * Eigen defines several typedef shortcuts for most common matrix and vector types.
  *
  * The general patterns are the following:
  *
  * \c MatrixSizeType where \c Size can be \c 2,\c 3,\c 4 for fixed size square matrices or \c X for dynamic size,
  * and where \c Type can be \c i for integer, \c f for float, \c d for double, \c cf for complex float, \c cd
  * for complex double.
  *
  * For example, \c Matrix3d is a fixed-size 3x3 matrix type of doubles, and \c MatrixXf is a dynamic-size matrix of floats.
  *
  * There are also \c VectorSizeType and \c RowVectorSizeType which are self-explanatory. For example, \c Vector4cf is
  * a fixed-size vector of 4 complex floats.
  *
  * \sa class Matrix
  */

#define EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS(Type, TypeSuffix, Size, SizeSuffix)   \
/** \ingroup matrixtypedefs */                                    \
typedef Matrix<Type, Size, Size> Matrix##SizeSuffix##TypeSuffix;  \
/** \ingroup matrixtypedefs */                                    \
typedef Matrix<Type, Size, 1>    Vector##SizeSuffix##TypeSuffix;  \
/** \ingroup matrixtypedefs */                                    \
typedef Matrix<Type, 1, Size>    RowVector##SizeSuffix##TypeSuffix;

#define EIGEN_MAKE_FIXED_TYPEDEFS(Type, TypeSuffix, Size)         \
/** \ingroup matrixtypedefs */                                    \
typedef Matrix<Type, Size, Dynamic> Matrix##Size##X##TypeSuffix;  \
/** \ingroup matrixtypedefs */                                    \
typedef Matrix<Type, Dynamic, Size> Matrix##X##Size##TypeSuffix;

#define EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS_ALL_SIZES(Type, TypeSuffix) \
EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS(Type, TypeSuffix, 2, 2) \
EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS(Type, TypeSuffix, 3, 3) \
EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS(Type, TypeSuffix, 4, 4) \
EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS(Type, TypeSuffix, Dynamic, X) \
EIGEN_MAKE_FIXED_TYPEDEFS(Type, TypeSuffix, 2) \
EIGEN_MAKE_FIXED_TYPEDEFS(Type, TypeSuffix, 3) \
EIGEN_MAKE_FIXED_TYPEDEFS(Type, TypeSuffix, 4)

EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS_ALL_SIZES(int,                  i)
EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS_ALL_SIZES(float,                f)
EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS_ALL_SIZES(double,               d)
EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS_ALL_SIZES(std::complex<float>,  cf)
EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS_ALL_SIZES(std::complex<double>, cd)

#undef EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS_ALL_SIZES
#undef EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS
#undef EIGEN_MAKE_FIXED_TYPEDEFS

} // end namespace Eigen

#endif // EIGEN_MATRIX_H
```

I got the next errors :

```
 D:\toolchain-master\LabelingTool\Dependencies\build_dir\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\Matrix.h:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Matrix'
D:\toolchain-master\LabelingTool\Dependencies\build_dir\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\Matrix.h:18: error: '_Scalar' does not refer to a value
  D:\toolchain-master\LabelingTool\Dependencies\build_dir\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\Matrix.h:18: error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'traits'
D:\toolchain-master\LabelingTool\Dependencies\build_dir\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\Matrix.h:179: error: unknown template name 'PlainObjectBase'
D:\toolchain-master\LabelingTool\Dependencies\build_dir\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\Matrix.h:186: error: no template named 'PlainObjectBase'
D:\toolchain-master\LabelingTool\Dependencies\build_dir\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\Matrix.h:190: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
D:\toolchain-master\LabelingTool\Dependencies\build_dir\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\Matrix.h:194: error: 'Eigen::Matrix::Base' (aka 'int') is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
D:\toolchain-master\LabelingTool\Dependencies\build_dir\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\Matrix.h:205: error: unknown type name 'EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC'
D:\toolchain-master\LabelingTool\Dependencies\build_dir\include\eigen3\Eigen\src\Core\Matrix.h:450: error: too few template arguments for class template 'Matrix'
................................................
```

I don't know if i link the library correctly , here is my .pro folder :

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
QT       += core gui charts

TARGET = LabelingTool
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0



INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib64 -losg -losgDB -losgGA -losgViewer -losgText
# LIBS += D:/Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/ -llibEGL -llibGLESv2 -lQt5AccessibilitySupport -lQt5AxBase -lQt5AxContainer -lQt5AxServer -lQt5Bluetooth -lQt5Bootstrap -lQt5Charts -lQt5Concurrent
SOURCES += \
        src/main.cpp \
        src/MainWindow/mainwindow.cpp \
        src/MainOsgViewer/mainosgviewer.cpp \
        src/LabelData/labeldata.cpp \
        src/LabelEventHandler/labeleventhandler.cpp \
        src/ImageView/imageview.cpp \
        src/InformationFormular/informationformular.cpp \
        src/Polynomial/polynomial.cpp \
        src/Chart/chart.cpp \
        src/LabelImage/labelimage.cpp \
        src/YamlReader/yamlreader.cpp \
        src/LabelBox/labelbox.cpp \
        src/SliderBar/sliderbar.cpp \
        src/LabelData/labeldata.cpp \



HEADERS += \
        src/MainWindow/mainwindow.h \
        src/MainOsgViewer/mainosgviewer.h \
        src/LabelData/labeldata.h \
        src/LabelEventHandler/labeleventhandler.h \
        src/ImageView/imageview.h \
        src/InformationFormular/informationformular.h \
        src/Polynomial/polynomial.h \
        src/Chart/chart.h \
        src/LabelImage/labelimage.h \
        src/YamlReader/yamlreader.h \
        src/LabelBox/labelbox.h \
        src/SliderBar/sliderbar.h \
        src/LabelData/labeldata.h \
        Dependencies/build_dir/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h \


DISTFILES += \
   CMakeLists.txt

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -lOpenThreads \
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -lOpenThreadsd \
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -lOpenThreads \

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include \
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include  \

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgAnimation
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgAnimationd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgAnimation

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losg
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losg

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgDB
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgDBd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgDB

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include



win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgFX
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgFXd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgFX

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include



win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgManipulator
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgManipulatord
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgManipulator

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include




win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgParticle
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgParticled
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgParticle

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgPresentation
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgPresentationd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgPresentation

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgShadow
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgShadowd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgShadow

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgSim
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgSimd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgSim

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgTerrain
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgTerraind
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgTerrain

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgText
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgTextd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgText

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgUI
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgUId
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgUI

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgUtil
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgUtild
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgUtil

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgViewer
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgViewerd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgViewer

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgVolume
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgVolumed
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgVolume

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgWidget
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgWidgetd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgWidget

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgGA
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgGAd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgGA

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/eigen-eigen
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/eigen-eigen


win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/yaml-cpp-masterr/lib/ -llibyaml-cppmd
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/yaml-cpp-masterr/lib/ -llibyaml-cppmdd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/yaml-cpp-masterr/lib/ -llibyaml-cppmd

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/yaml-cpp-masterr/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/yaml-cpp-masterr/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losg
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losgd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/lib/ -losg

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/OSG.3.4.0/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Core
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Cored
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Core

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Gui
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Guid
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Gui

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Svg
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Svgd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Svg

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Widgets
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Widgetsd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Widgets

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Script
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Scriptd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5Script

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lqtmain
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lqtmaind
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lqtmain

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5QuickWidgets
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5QuickWidgetsd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/lib/ -lQt5QuickWidgets

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Qt/5.11.2/msvc2015/include
```

.................................................................................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't  use qt, so take this with a grain of salt. You have two possible issues that I see:

1. In the
   `HEADERS += \
   ....
       Dependencies/build_dir/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h \`
   I think you shoud be using `Dependencies/build_dir/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core` instead.
2. The lines:
   `INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/eigen-eigen
   DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dependencies/eigen-eigen`
   seem to have a different path than the included path in item '1' above. This may not be an issue if the two directories are identical, but if not, you'll have version mismatch issues.